# Google Maps API V3 - Opening All Info Windows Attached to Markers in Current View Bounds?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following listener on my maps object:

```
    myMapObject.addListener('bounds_changed', function(){
        mySearchBoxObject.setBounds(myMapObject.getBounds());
        if(this.getZoom() == 14){
            for(var i = 0; i < customInfoWindows.length; i++){
                customInfoWindows[i].open(myMapObject, customMarkers[i]);
            }
        }
    });
```

At zoom level 14, I automatically open up all info windows bound to custom markers I have placed on the map.

Is there a way to use the info provided by the API to open only info windows that are within the current view of my zoom?  For example, if I have 20 markers / info windows on my map and I can only see 4 markers in my current zoomed view, I only want to open the 4 info windows associate with those 4 markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the marker is within the bounds before opening the infowindow:

```
myMapObject.addListener('bounds_changed', function(){
    mySearchBoxObject.setBounds(myMapObject.getBounds());
    if(this.getZoom() == 14){
        for(var i = 0; i < customInfoWindows.length; i++){
            // check if is in bounds
            if (myMapObject.getBounds().contains(customMarkers[i].getPosition()))
                customInfoWindows[i].open(myMapObject, customMarkers[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

[google.maps.Map.getBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) method returns a [google.maps.LatLngBounds()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object which has a `.contains` method.

> **contains**(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)
>
> Return Value:  boolean
>
> Returns true if the given lat/lng is in this bounds.

Comment: Beautiful, do you have the URL that documents the `contains()` method?

Comment: added to the answer